Why can't I find the intersection point between this parametric plane and line?
We have the plane defined in normal form by:

\begin{equation}
x + y - 2z - 2 = 0
\end{equation}

To convert this to parametric form using the orthogonal vectors $\mathbf{u} = (1, 1, 1)$, $\mathbf{v} = (-1, 1, 0)$, and the point $P = (0, 0, -1)$, we get:
\begin{cases}
x = 0 + s - t \\
y = 0 + s + t \\
z = -1 + s
\end{cases}
The line is defined by the point $Q = (1, 1, 1)$ and the directional vector $\mathbf{l} = (3, 0, 1)$, and its parametric form is:
\begin{cases}
x = 1 + 3t \\
y = 1 \\
z = 1 + t
\end{cases}
To find the intersection, we set up the following system of linear equations:
\begin{cases}
1 + 3t = s - t \\
1 = s + t \\
1 + t = -1 + s
\end{cases}
Simplifying each equation, we get:
\begin{cases}
1 + 4t - s = 0 \\
1 - s - t = 0 \\
2 + t - s = 0
\end{cases}
Solving this system, we observe that there is no solution. However, we know that the plane and the line intersect at $(7, 1, 3)$.
To verify, we substitute $x = 7$, $y = 1$, $z = 3$ into the plane equation:

$1*7+1*1-2*3-2=0$

which is true.
Why doesn't It work when I try to use the equations from the parametric forms, please explain.

Because you can't use the same parameter, $t$, in both the plane and the line. Pick a new one, say $u$, for the line.

@JonathanZ Thank you, intuatively is using the same parameter t for both the line and the plane like trying to fit the plane and the line but every time you move the line point you move the plane point as well?

Yeah, that's a good way to put it. You've connected their motions unnecessarily, and you need them to move independently to get to the intersection point. (Although it might be possible that the the two $t$'s have value at the intersection point, but it's unlikely, and we certainly can't assume it.)
